# c# error : length cannot be less than 0

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my C# program: I have created a quiz with 10 questions and 10 images.
I get this `Length cannot be less than zero.\r\nParameter name: length` at the line

```
int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter));
```

Even if in my notepad file I included the image index:

```
3:What is the foo in the bar? 
10:How can you add a widget? 
4:Why pick a bar over a foo?
```

Here is the code:

```
if (nr >= questions.Count)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int x;
    do   
    { 
        x = r.Next(questions.Count); 
    } 
    while (questions[x].displayed == true);

    textBox1.Text = questionText;
    radioButton1.Text = questions[x].answer1; 
    radioButton2.Text = questions[x].answer2;
    questions[x].displayed= true;
    current_question = x;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `delimiter` at the point at which you invoke `Substring`?

Comment: The error means what it says. I recommend reading the documentation on `String.Substring()` .

Comment: are you sure there are no empty lines in the questions array. 
I have found many times that while reading from file (File.ReadAllLines()), empty lines causes problem when line is parsed and further operations are done.

Answer (score 5):

You've previously got a line like this:

```
int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':');
```

... but you're then not checking the return value. If it's -1, that means your delimiter wasn't found in that particular line - but you're passing it into `Substring` anyway. Check the value of `delimiter` before you use it - that way you can throw a more useful exception (or skip the line, or whatever you want to do).

I would actually suggest that you change your code significantly - instead of keeping `questions` as a `List<string>` or whatever it is, I'd create a `Question` class. Parse the lines of text as you read them, discarding failures - or throwing an exception - at that point, rather than waiting until you happen to hit the bad question. You can then have a `List<Question>` which will make the rest of the code simpler.

You might *also* want to keep a `Queue<Question>` which is initially a copy of the complete list, shuffled. When you want to show a new question, just take the next element from that queue. That way you won't need to loop round while you pick already-shown questions. (You'll want to include an `Index` or `QuestionNumber` property within the `Question` class, presumably...)

Note that it's possible that it's working for all the lines that you're really aware of, but that you've got some empty lines at the end of your file. You may well just want to skip empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

Substring parameters are initial index, and length. delimiter from the code does not looks like length.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Change following

```
int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':'); 
int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter)); 
string questionText=line.Substring(delimiter + 1); 
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imageIndex];  

textBox1.Text = questionText;
radioButton1.Text = questions[x].answer1;  
questions[x].displayed= true; 
current_question = x;
```

To

```
int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':'); 
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && delimiter > 0 )
    {
        int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter)); 
        string questionText=line.Substring(delimiter + 1); 
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imageIndex];  

        textBox1.Text = questionText;
        radioButton1.Text = questions[x].answer1;  
        questions[x].displayed= true; 
        current_question = x; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private string copystring(string instr ,int start ,int length)
{
    return instr.Length >= (start + 1) 
        ? (instr.Length > (start + length) ? instr.Substring(start, length) : instr.Substring(start,instr.Length-start)) 
        : "";
}
```